# Elasticsearch indexing while rollover

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have an application which writes to the ES and which also schedules time based index rollover based on `max_docs` condition.

- What will happen if I try indexing during the rollover ?
- Does ES takes lock while performing rollover ?
- On an average how much time does it take to rollover the index ? Acc. to me this shouldn't take much time as time based index rollover is just creating a new index and pointing the alias to it.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question on elastic discuss and it got answered there.

Copying the answer here :

> Remember that you are sending your index operation to an alias.
>
> What happens when you rollover:
>
> - It creates a new index (You are still indexing to the old index       through the alias).
> - It switches the alias. This switch is super    fast. If you have a pending operation it might go to the old index.
>
> Once done, the new requests will go to the new index.
>
> There is no lock.

For reference : [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-indexing-while-rollover/112158)